# open link inside anchor_popup

Tags: html, url, popup, href

I am having a problem with links inside my popup window that I've create using php. I've used anchor_popup property. If I simply put this inside my window and try clicking on it I get the same window I've clicked from.

```
<a href="www.google.com" tagert="_blank">google</a>
```

if I hover on the link i get the http://www.mysite.com/xxx/www.google.com

Is it even possible to open it from popup window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browser interpret it as internal link use http

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" tagert="_blank">google</a>
```